# What's the best way to handle an image property in a POST request to sanity CMS using Reactjs and Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I am unable to handle the image property passed in my POST request because it is a file.

What I'm trying to do is make a POST request to my sanity CMS that will add properties like name, image, description etc. but the image property is not being passed correctly but all the other props are working just fine. I have a form that will take inputs and when submitted should push all the properties to my sanity CMS. I know there is something wrong that I'm doing but I can't quite pin it.

Here is my `AddDessert` component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const AddDessert = () => {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowForm(true);
  };

  const FormModal = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);
    const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState("");

    const handleAddIngredient = () => {
      setIngredients([...ingredients, ""]);
    };

    const handleIngredientChange = (index, value) => {
      const updatedIngredients = [...ingredients];
      updatedIngredients[index] = value;
      setIngredients(updatedIngredients);
    };

    const postDessert = async () => {
      const dessertInfo = {
        name: name,
        image: image,
        timer: timer,
        description: description,
        ingredients: ingredients,
        recipe: recipe,
      };
      console.log(dessertInfo);

      const result = await fetch(`/api/addDessert`, {
        body: JSON.stringify(dessertInfo),
        method: "POST",
      });

      const json = await result.json();
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      postDessert();

      // Submit the form data
      // You can access the form values using the state variables
    };
    const handleBackdropClick = (e) => {
      if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
        setShowForm(false);
      }
    };
    return (
      <AnimatePresence>
        {showForm && (
          <motion.div
            initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
            className="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-75"
            onClick={handleBackdropClick}
          >
            <div className="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg max-h-[90vh] overflow-auto">
              <h2 className="textstyle text-[#e5799b] text-bold text-center">
                Add Dessert
              </h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="max-w-lg mx-auto">
                <div className="mb-4 mt-2">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="name"
                    className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-1"
                  >
                    Name of Dessert:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    className="w-full px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-4">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="image"
                    className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-1"
                  >
                    Upload Image:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    id="image"
                    className="w-full bg-transparent text-gray-700"
                    onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-4">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="timer"
                    className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-1"
                  >
                    Timer:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="timer"
                    className="w-full px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                    value={timer}
                    onChange={(e) => setTimer(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-4">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="description"
                    className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-1"
                  >
                    Short Description:
                  </label>
                  <textarea
                    id="description"
                    className="w-full px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                    value={description}
                    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                  ></textarea>
                </div>

                <div className="mb-4">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="ingredients"
                    className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-1"
                  >
                    Ingredients:
                  </label>
                  {ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => (
                    <input
                      key={index}
                      type="text"
                      className="w-full px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 rounded-md mb-2 focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                      value={ingredient}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        handleIngredientChange(index, e.target.value)
                      }
                    />
                  ))}
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="bg-[#e5799b] hover:bg-[#e5799b] hover:bg-opacity-75 text-white py-1 px-3 rounded"
                    onClick={handleAddIngredient}
                  >
                    Add Ingredient
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div className="mb-4">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="recipe"
                    className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-1"
                  >
                    Recipe of the Dessert:
                  </label>
                  <textarea
                    id="recipe"
                    className="w-full px-3 py-2 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                    value={recipe}
                    onChange={(e) => setRecipe(e.target.value)}
                  ></textarea>
                </div>

                {/* Submit button */}
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="bg-[#e5799b] hover:bg-[#e5799b] hover:bg-opacity-75 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-md"
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className=" min-w-[140px] md:w-[180px] min-h-[180px] md:h-[220px] rounded-[10px] border-[3px] border-white cursor-pointer"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full text-white">
          <span className="text-[25px] font-extrabold">+</span>
          <p className="textstyle text-[20px]">
            Add
            <br />
            your
            <br />
            dessert
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {showForm && <FormModal />}
    </>
  );
};

export default AddDessert;

And here's my api route

// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const data = JSON.parse(req.body);

  const mutations = {
    mutations: [
      {
        create: {
          _type: "dessert",
          name: data.name,
          image: data.image,
          timer: data.timer,
          description: data.description,
          ingredients: data.ingredients,
          recipe: data.recipe,
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  const apiEndpoint = `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/mutate/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET}`;

  const result = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SANITY_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(mutations),
    method: "POST",
  });

  const json = await result.json();
  res.status(201).json({ message: "Added" });
}
```

I tried using sanity `imageUrlBuilder` from sanity to get the image url but it doesn't work for me.